# LocalNotifications on iOS not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I have an issue with LocalNotifications on my iOS-App.

On my App the user can schedule a Notification to get a reminder when a contract expires. He can choose the date and time himself.
However I have repeatedly been getting E-Mails from users, saying that their Notifications do not work.
When testing on my own personal device however, I have no issue and they work fine.

I was wondering if I was missing some comprehension about LocalNotifications. Do they expire at some point? Does the UNUserNotificationCenter delete queued notifications when a device is turned off? Are there any possible reasons for this behaviour or did anybody else encounter such a behaviour?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I included my code for creating a LocalNotification below:

```
/**
 Schedules a local notification.
 - parameter company: String! of the contracts company name.
 - parameter name: String! of the contracts name.
 - parameter datum: Date! of the reminder.
 
 - returns: String of NotificationID.
 */
static func scheduleNotification(company: String!, name: String!, datum: Date!) -> String! {
    let notificationID = arc4random()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = NSLocalizedString("Kündigungserinnerung ", comment: "") + company
    content.body = NSLocalizedString("Falls Sie Ihren ", comment: "") + name + NSLocalizedString(" Vertrag kündigen möchten, wäre jetzt der richtige Zeitpunkt dafür! ", comment: "")
    content.categoryIdentifier = Notification.Category.Local.identifier
    content.userInfo = ["NotificationID": notificationID]
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: datum)

    // UnMark to check if Notifications work
    //let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

    let finalComponents = NSDateComponents()
    finalComponents.year = components.year!
    finalComponents.month = components.month!
    finalComponents.day = components.day!
    finalComponents.hour = components.hour!
    finalComponents.minute = components.minute!

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: finalComponents as DateComponents, repeats: false)
    let requestIdentifier = "request"
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
        if error != nil {
            log.error(error!)
        }
    })
    return String(notificationID)

}
```

Comment: Have you requested and received authorisation from the user to fire notifications before attempting to do so?

Comment: Yes, permission has been granted by the user. I have users sending me screenshots of their notification settings and they are granted and should be working. @teacup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from a different forum which solved my issue:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658282